# How to find Real circuit diagrams used by computer industry consisting of NAND Gates or NOR Gate

Tags: logic-gates

It is said that the circuit diagrams used by computer industry consisting mainly of NAND Gates or NOR Gates. (as oppossed to the text book circuit diagrams which contain the cicuit diagrams with every kind of Gates). Here is my question: Where can i find those real circuit diagrams used in the computer industry on the web (using solely or mainly NAND or NOR Gates)?

Comment: "It is said":  By whom?

Comment: Get hold of "The TTL Data Book".

Comment: It is said in some computer/electrical engineering related text books.And it is the manufacturing process of digital circuits that use mainly NAND or NOR Gates.

Comment: There are about 50 logic families of various TTL ECL CMOS with various detailed designs. which one?

Comment: Maybe look for a somewhat advanced digital logic textbook. The one I know is the one by [Rabaey](https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Integrated-Circuits-Design-Perspective/dp/8120322576/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1501776535&sr=8-2-fkmr0&keywords=Jean+Rabaey), but that's getting fairly old now and there's probably something newer now.

Comment: Go thru the trash outside the semiconductor houses. Or the MCU design centers.

Answer (score 3):

For some functions, data sheets show underlying logic. For example a 74HC74 flip flop data sheet shows this:
[image: underlying logic of a flip flop]

In this case, four basic functions (five if you count the hysteresis input) are used: NAND, NOR, Transmission gate, inverter. Be aware that different logic families take advantage of their logic peculiarities to simplify or to improve speed of their functional operation - an emitter-coupled logic (ECL) flip flop looks nothing like this.
 Data sheets might show underlying logic of the simpler functions like synchronous counters, encoders/decoders, adders. Beyond an arithmetic logic unit (ALU) like a 74181, the logic breakdown becomes complex enough that diagrams like this convey little useful information. But they might be useful to show the progression from simple-to-complex.
As others have noted, old logic data books often had chapters introducing 'new' logic families to designers who needed upgrading to the improved technology - before web publishing. Lots of extra details on how to use chips in 'new' designs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends at what level you look at the gates. A 2 input CMOS NAND or NOR gate requires 4 transistors. A NOT gate requires 2 transistors. An AND gate is basically a NAND gate with an NOT gate on the output.

Which means that physically within the devices you will have NAND and NOR gates but they will be arranged in a way to logically produce whatever logic function is required by the design.

Comment: But not all gates are AND - I believe more complex gates are also common in modern technolgies, no longer restricting them to NAND, NOR and inverters.

Comment: There are 6 basic types of gate, AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR and NOT. Almost all digital electronics are built of these gates and you can build any of them out of NAND or NOR gates which are the most efficient type to make using a CMOS process. What other types of gate are you thinking of?

Comment: Those are the 2-port gates (and the inverter with 1 port). Nothing stops you from implementing more complex logic functions in a single gate - it might not have a nice name like "AND", "OR" or whatever but it is still a gate.

Comment: Additionally, if you go to different types of logic (dynamic, differential, current-mode) I believe different gates become the "basic" building blocks (dual-rail domino has AND gates but not NAND in a single stage, if memory serves me right)

Comment: True, any complex multi input gate can be created using NAND or NOR gates however at a silicon level there may be a more efficient way to produce a complex function. And then there is always the FPGA method, a 4x1 SRAM can implement any arbitrary 4 input logic function, not remotely transistor efficient but flexible and by using a standard cell you can build in redundancy and so boost yield.

Answer (score 0):

"It is said":  By whom? 
Historically, yes, it was common because NAND and NOR can be made easily on chip - but with more modern logic synthesis tools, I wouldn't dare asume most gates are NAND and NORs. Also, the reason why you don't find digital diagrams with gates on the web is because (almost) nobody design on the gate level anymore - modern digital circuits are designed in [HDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language) (hardware description languages) - using VHDL or Verilog to describe what the hardware should do, and programs then turn this into actual gates. This is called [logic synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis).

The only real cases where people still design on gate-level (although often they would even decend to the transistor level) is for the core building blocks that have to be very fast - in applications like SRAM buffers, adders, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,So, how can I find "core building blocks" (buffers, adders) which are really used in the industry? Because designers of those "core building blocks" pay more attention to design cost effective , energy consuming  designs, I think they must be different from the designs given in the text books. And I want to have a comparison.

Comment: I don't know what textbook you are using, but the ones I have have some pretty "common in industry" blocks. Also, open literature on source like IEEE Explore and such might be worth looking at.

Comment: What you need is what a foundry calls a "technology library" - that will give you the building blocks. Unfortunately stuff used in the industry is seldom free. But again, what exactly are you hoping to find out?

Comment: "NAND and NOR can be made easily on chip". Its no harder to make an AND or an OR gate than a NAND or a NOR. however the NAND and NOR take 4 transistors to make while the AND and OR take 6. So the use of NAND and NOR was mainly a space saving decision.

Comment: I considered "being smaller for a given sizing" easier - easier to build a given amount of gates with a certain area. In this sense it's no harder to build a big CPU than it is to build a simple inverter - it just takes more transistors

Comment: How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go? A 'D' flipflop in an introductory text is often (for example) implemented as a pair of clocked SR latches and some inverters, and that is not a horrible model at that level (It is also not how any chip designer will do it). A better model involves a couple of transmission gates with carefully controlled doping to get the sequencing right, but the details depend a LOT on the technology in use, a multi GHz GaAs prescaler is different to jellybean cmos. You need that tech library.